# Why use Regression in NN?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, linear, function

In a NN we first apply a Linear Function, ie. Multiplying the weights to the inputs/output of a layer and then apply a Non-Linear Activation function like ReLU to get the output of the layer. The first step ie. Linear Function is exactly the same we do in Regression, so **why do we use Regression as an intermediate step when doing NN?** Why aren't we doing something else like performing some other function with the weights and inputs say divide/square/ anything else? I understand that NN are wonderful function estimators, what's so special with the Linear Function which helps it achieve that and not with some other function?

This might sound trivial but I'm unable understand this.

***Any help is highly appreciated.***

Comment: @CowboyTrader, I meant that for every layer, the outputs/activations of the previous layer say [l-1] and the weights for the current layer [l] we essentially do the Linear step for all such layers [l] not just for the first layer. So we do regression for every layer in that manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special but there are some observations to be done. It is true that it is a linear combination and applying the activation function gives a regression. However this is not a linear regression unless we have an identity as activation. An indeed using identity we will get a linear regression in the end. If we use logistic sigmoid, then the NN will be a logistic regression. There are three arguments in favor of current setup. Historical: it mimics the neuron behavior. Computation: there are fast vectorized operations to help you carry a lot of operations in short time. Mathematical: devising error propagation through gradients is much easier. And maybe another one: the NN could be highly nonlinear enough to approximate a lot of surfaces, what would bring to the table a different approach to give enough advantages over the classical setup. However I am not saying that it would not be successful, but that it is hard to overcome the advantages of current setup